# AMQP.Net Credit doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: c#, amqp

I am having a problem fully understanding the “credit” property used with AMQP.Net. The way it reads it appears that it can be used to prevent the sender queuing up too much data. If I set the credit to a low value, when the credit runs out the “ResponseLink.Closed” event fires and the process stops. What I would like to do is to set a credit so that when the receiver is overwhelmed, the sender can pause to allow the receiver to catch-up a bit and then start sending again from where it left off. At the moment, the sender is queuing up so much data that the computer runs out of memory as the receiver is running slow. Is this possible by using credit or should an alternative solution need to be used?

## Update

The way I am using AMQP.Net at the moment is that the client makes a call to the server requesting that data is sent of a certain type. The server makes a call to the database and gets back a very large list of data. This data is then sent to the client from a foreach loop using:

```
requestContext.Complete( ** an item of data goes in here **)
```

The client is getting these via the OnMessage event at its end. Because the send is quicker than the client can handle them, the memory usage grows quickly. How is it possible to get some feedback on the server side to know when the client has handled n number of messages so that it can pause before sending more?

Comment: Credit is used by the sender (the library) to limit the number of messages that can be sent to the remote peer. If the application keeps calling Send, messages will be queued in the library when no credits are available. Credit is determined by the receiver and it is meant to protect the receiver. For you scenario, why do you keep calling send when many messages are still queued? The link closed event should be caused by some other error. If you post an issue on github with more details, I can look into it.

Comment: I would love to not send messages when they are starting to get queued but I can't see a way of knowing that the queue is growing. How would I check for this?

Comment: Which API you call to send the messages? Do you wait (or await) the Send call to return, or do you provide an OutcomeCallback delegate to handle the outcome? Either way the library gives you a way to get the outcome of a sent message and your application should know how many messages have been sent but not acknowledged.

Comment: I have added an updated section to my original question to explain how I am using the AMQP library. May be I'm not using it right for what I need to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update gives a better description of how you use the library and the problem you are running into. Depending what you have in the request message, there are two solutions you can try.

1. if you always have a lot of data for a client request, you can switch to use a single receiver link from the client. On the listener side, you register a link processor (ILinkProcessor) and create a SourceLinkEndpoint when receiving a link attach request. You can pass request specific data in attach.properties when you create the link. You will also need to implement the IMessageSource interface. The library will invoke your method implementations on flow and acknowledgement events. In the GetMessageAsync method you can query the database to get the data that fits in just one message, or a list of items to fill a in-memory cache from which the GetMessageAsync call is served. You close the link after all data is transferred. In this model, the AMQP link flow control will take place in message transfer and you have full control of how much memory can be used for a link.
2. If you prefer the request/response model, you would need to implement some paging logic to avoid high memory consumption on the listener side. The request/response pattern is build on top of the standard AMQP message transfer using a pair of links. The flow control in one link is independent of the other and cannot be used to coordinate transfers of request and response messages. Instead of serving all data to one client request, you could send requests more frequently and serve only a fixed-size (or number) of messages to each request.

Comment: If your origin question is about the IRequestProcessor.Credit property, it is the credit given to the client request (sender) link. It determines how many concurrent requests the client can push to the processor on the listener side.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We have started to use some paging logic and will see how we get on with that. This approach minimises the number of changes we need to make to our existing system.